# How to create a single array using two iterating loop and than update_batch

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How do I take `id` on every iteration from `check_seeds` array and add on each itteration into `seeded[]` array.

In more simple words, I want to take an item from the first iteration and add into the first iteration, take an item from the second iteration and add into the second iteration and so on...

Actually, on update_batch we need third parameter (primary key, index) to update array values in database rows where `id` from database rows matches with the `id` in `update_batch`.

```
$check_seeds = $this->tournament_model->get_seeds($tournament_id);
$seeds = $this->input->post('seed');
foreach ($seeds as $key => $value){
    if(!empty($key) && !empty($value)){
        $seeded[] = array(
            'id' => (Add id here),
            'tournament_id' => $tournament_id,
            'stage_id' => $stage_id,
            'seed_id' => $value,
            'team_name' => $key,
        );
    $this->db->update_batch('tournament_seed', $seeded, 'id');
    redirect('organizer/tournaments);
    }
}
```

**print_r($check_seeds)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [tournament_id] => 713161746
            [stage_id] => 3
            [seed_id] => 3
            [team_name] => -V-ATTAX
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [tournament_id] => 713161746
            [stage_id] => 3
            [seed_id] => 3
            [team_name] => -V-ATTAX
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [tournament_id] => 713161746
            [stage_id] => 3
            [seed_id] => 3
            [team_name] => -V-ATTAX
        )

)
```

Comment: What's this ID? Is it PK?

Comment: What is that array key `id`? Is that the primary key of your table that you need to update? I can't understand what you're asking, try to reformulate your question.

Comment: Yes, please elaborate. There appears to be only one loop (iterator) so what do you mean my "first iteration" and "second iteration"?

Comment: It looks to me like there will be only one pass through the loop due to the `redirect()` call. `redirect()` does not return and it ends script execution with a call to `exit`.

Comment: Tell me if I understand: you need to update `$check_seeds` with `$seeded` array? So you need to get those `ids` from `$check_seeds` and populate `$seeded` array?

Comment: I need to update table "tournament_seed" in the database. but first I need to get row ids which we will be going to update using update_batch. Look at print_r($check_seeds). Let suppose in our case those are three ids 3, 4 & 5. Now i want to place them one by one into seeded[] array and update my database. on first iteration I will get 3 and than we will place that 3 in seeded[] array and update. than second iteration start and we take 4 and place it in second iteration on seeded[] array and so on..

Comment: Is easier if you have those values on `post` data.

Answer (score 0):

in your model function get_seeds() you can query the current max value of id as an alias and return it together with the query result:

```
function get_seeds($tournament_id) {
    $this->db->select_max('id', 'max_id');
    $this->db->where('tournament_id', $tournament_id);
    $result = $this->db->get('tournament_seed');
    return $result->result();
}
```

then in your controller's for_each() you increment that value:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($seeds as $key => $value){
    $i++;
    $seeded[] = array(
      'id' => $value->max_id + $i,
       //....
    );
}
```

Codeigniter docs: [Selecting Data](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data), scroll down to select_max(), as there is no internal bookmark